# Unify the color of graduated classes across several maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.4

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4 (advanced license).

The two maps below don't have the same minimum and maximum values.

[image]

[image]

I have tried using Save As layer file > Import symbology but it didn't work?

How is it possible to unify the graduated colors across the two layers?

Comment: You will have to re-classify your images to the same values as your colours and ranges, as they do not match.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Layer properties -> Symbology -> Graduated`, you need to define the number of classes to be equal in both maps, and click on `Classify -> break values` and change the break values to be equal in both maps, except the maximum value for both maps:

[image]

[image]

The output will be like this, and you have to repeat that for the second map, or save it as layer (.lyr) and apply on the other map:

[image]